# execute a function after previous function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to call a function after the previous function is complete? In the code below the `second_function()` is executed before the `first_function()` and the data get suffled

```js
first_function();
second_function();

function name() {
  if (condition == true) {
    let tdbody = document.createElement('td');
    tdbody.classList.add("class1");
    let tdbodytext = document.createTextNode(userincourseres[i].fullname);
    tdbody.appendChild(tdbodytext);
    trbody.appendChild(tdbody);
  }
}


async function first_function() {
  await name();
  if (condition == true) {
    var tdbody = document.createElement('td');
    var tdbodytext = document.createTextNode(get_grade_res.grade);
    tdbody.classList.add("class2");
    tdbody.appendChild(tdbodytext);
    trbody.appendChild(tdbody);
  }
}

function second_function() {
  if (condition == true) {
    var tdbody = document.createElement('td');
    var tdbodytext = document.createTextNode(get_grade_res.grade);
    tdbody.classList.add("class3");
    tdbody.appendChild(tdbodytext);
    trbody.appendChild(tdbody);
  }
```

Comment: If you are in async context, you may want to write : `await first_function()` at the first line

Comment: I’m not sure I understand; what’s asynchronous here? What makes you think something is happening out-of-order?

Comment: An `async` function returns a Promise, so it should be `await`ed. If you don't await it, the Promise will be executed/resolved in the next cycle, whereas synchronous code (the second function) is executed immediately. The first function is therefore executed after the second one.

Comment: I'm retrieving data through API , if I remove the async  the second function will execute first and data get shuffled

Comment: use Promises instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is expected, please have a look of the below example.

```js
first_function();
second_function();

function name() {
  console.log("name");
}

async function first_function() {
  await name();
  console.log("first");
}

function second_function() {
  console.log("second");
}
```

It can be written as

```js
function name() {
  console.log("name");
}

function second_function() {
  console.log("second");
}

Promise.resolve(name()).then(() => {
  console.log("first");
});

second_function();
```

Comment: I called the first_function(); at the beginning then I wrap the second function in a new function with setTimeout and it executed after 5 second `function run_in_sequence() {
    setTimeout((function() {
      second_function();
    }), 5000);
}

run_in_sequence(); `  I want this but without 5000 , just when the first function complete

Comment: @Abdallah_mohammad_90, you can just do `setTimeout( ()=>{ second_function(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Either do it like this

```
first_function().then(() => first_function())
```

Or if you want to use the async\await syntax

```
async function callingFunc() {
   await first_function();
   second_function();
}
```

Comment: If this is not working it means that you are not awaiting the promise you have in the first question. In the code you provided there is no call to to an API so we cant really help you